# Toggle class only on the div that is being hovered

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

I would like to know if there's a way to toggle a class only o the div that is being currently hovered.

My current code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

   $(".recipe-content").hover(function(){

     $(".recipe").toggleClass("hover");

   });

});

</script>
```

The code works but the problem is that the toggle is being executed on other divs that I have with the same name.

How could I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$(this)` is the specific element where the element is being occurred at:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $(".recipe-content").hover(function(){

     $(this).toggleClass("hover");

   });

});
```